# Angular Material Form Input Acting Strange

Tags: angular, forms

I have a very simple mat-form-field, and it's acting funny. When I type in a value, it deselects after each letter I type:

```
<div *ngFor="let phone of user.phones; let i = index">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
           matTooltip="Enter a phone number"
           [(ngModel)]="user.phones[i]"
           name="phone{{i}}"
           placeholder="Primary phone">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

When I remove `[(ngModel)]="user.phones[i]"` it works fine, but then it's not doing what I need it to do. `user.phones[]` is just an array of strings. Am I missing something obvious?

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  phones: string[];
}
```

console.log()

```
name: "John",
phones:Array(3)
  0:"4-43235"
  1:"654-65498"
  2:"fs48j3w"
  length:3
  __proto__:Array(0)
```

Comment: Can you define what you want it to do? Also can you provide the data of `user` and `user.phones` just so we can reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `trackBy` with the index for example. The reason is that you're binding to primitives in the array. I.e. `string`;

You could use something like:

**TEMPLATE**

```
<div *ngFor="let phone of user.phones; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput matTooltip="Enter a phone number" [(ngModel)]="user.phones[i]" name="phone{{i}}" placeholder="Primary phone">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  user = {
    phones: [
      "4-43235",
      "654-65498",
      "654-123123"
    ]
  }

  trackByIndex(index: number, value: number) {
    return index;
  }
}
```

I've put a demo with the working code.
Hope this helps: 
APP: https://angular-npqqa7.stackblitz.io
CODE: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npqqa7

Comment: That did it! Thank you :D

Comment: Happy to help ;)